# Best way to include Utility class in angular 6

Tags: angular

When my angular 6 project is in prod mode the assets folder gets moved out of src. It's set that way in webpack config.

So I'm brand new to Angular. I'd like a clean way to reference the path to my assets based on NODE_ENV. I'd like to do this:

```
// Utility class
class Utilities {
  public static getAssetsPath(env) {
    return env == 'dev' ? 'src/assets' : '../assets';
  }
  private constructor() {}
}

// Component class
import {Utils} from 'shared/utilities/utils';

class MyComponent {

const ENVIRONMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV;
constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const eventUrl = /(?<=\/).+/.exec(event.urlAfterRedirects);
        const currentRoute = (eventUrl || []).join('');
            this.myIcon =
              Utils.getAssetPath(ENVIRONMENT) + '/icons/myIcon.png';
        }
    });
  }
    }
```

But I'm guessing there's a more Angular way to do this so every component will have access to it without having to import the Utilities class. Like a provider, for instance. Is my solution not the Angular-way to do it? Thanks for any pro tips.

Comment: Utils class (not provider) is a classe that only contains `static and pure functions`.
For external informations it depend where you need the information because I personally use "Container Presentational" Architecture. That mean you can not get information in Presentational Components in other way than using `[@input]`

Answer (score 1):

In your component, you add where is the image like this

```html
 <img src="../assets/icons/myIcon.png"/>
```

You shouldn´t have problems when you deploy your application using the following command

```
 ng build
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The angular cli should allow me to simply do assets/. But it appears that webpack is configured to only allow it to see src/assets.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to create a component that represents an image and pass the image path to the component. Use the component's selector in the html like so:

```
<my-image-component [path]="'/icons/myIcon.png'"></my-image-component>
```

This way the utilities class only has to be injected in the image component.